# Overriding mappings for a map of basic types

Tags: java, annotations, jpa-2.0

I'm working on a JPA 2.0 compliancy kit for my internship... Part of that kit is testing corner cases.

JSR-317 states on Page 360 that "The `AttributeOverride` annotation may be applied to an element collection containing instances of an embeddable class or to a *map collection whose key and/or value is an embeddable class.*"

How then, do I, according to JPA 2.0, override the mapping of a map of basic types? I know I can use @MapKeyColumn to map the key of the map, and I'm sure there is some way to map the value side of the @CollectionTable as well...

But how would I go about overriding these?

Consider an @Embeddable with a map

```
@CollectionTable
@MapKeyColumn(name="differentname_KEY")
Map<Integer, String> testMap;
```

How would I go about overriding the key and the value? Do I use @AttributeOverride, or something else? (Or is it impossible?!)

I'm assuming here that such a map would be mapped with a @CollectionTable, so please correct me if I'm wrong.
If JPA doesn't give an answer, I'd be interested in knowing how persistence providers have solved this problem.

EDIT:
Viruzzo commented that basic types are embeddable types.
I'm willing to accept that, but something is holding me back:
JSR-317 is referring to an embeddable *class* (see upper quote). Type and class are not the same...

Comment: Basic types are embeddable; I'd say it's just a poor choice of words.

Comment: If you added that as an answer I could accept it...
Are you sure there's not a difference? There's a difference in depth from what I've seen: in case of an embeddable it would be `@AttributeOverride(name="embeddable.testMap.key.attribute" [column omitted])` and in case of a basic type it would then be `@AttributeOverride(name="embeddable.testMap.key" [column omitted])`.

Comment: @MapKeyClass also states that "The map key can be a basic type, an embeddable class, or an entity.", leading to further support that an embeddable type is not the same as an embeddable class.

Comment: I didn't say they are the same, just that basic types are embeddable (not an embeddable *class*); simply put, an embeddable *class* is one that is incorporated inside the container class when passed to JPA, which is the native (and only) behaviour for basic types.

Comment: Okay, ... ... how does that answer the question? I'm having trouble understanding it.

Comment: Supposedly you can use `@AttributeOverride`

Comment: Are there any persistence providers that allow you to use `@AttributeOverride` in that manner?

Answer (score 1):

First as a side note: Map in your example should not even compile. Reason is that int is primitive type, `java.util.Collection` collection and map interfaces and implementations are only for references types.

Lets use instead following example:

```
SomeEntity {
  @Id private int id;
  @ElementCollection
  private Map<Integer, String> testmap; 
}
```

By default testMap is mapped to the table `SomeEntity_TESTMAP(SOMEENTITY_ID, TESTMAP, TESTMAPKEY)`. We have defaulted table name and three defaulted
column names. It is possible to override all of these. Following will map to the table testmap_table(join_column, value_column, key_column):

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "testmap_table", 
                 joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "join_column"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "key_column")
@Column(name= "value_column")
private Map<Integer, String> testMap;
```

@AttributeOverride have no use here because no key or value is embeddable. It is for overriding mappings derived from elsewhere, not for overriding defaults of ElementCollection. It does have two usages:

- overriding attribute mappings derived from mapped superclass or
  derived from the embedded class
- overriding attribute mappings derived from the embeddable class that
  is used as key or value in element collection.

Comment: fixed the compilation error, thanks. I'll look at this in more detail when I arrive at work tomorrow... I see that `@AttributeOverride` can't be used here - what would be used?

Comment: Used for what, can you give example about functionality you miss? In example I gave there is three columns and for all of them default name of the column is overridden (@JoinColumn, MapKeyColumn, @Column).

Comment: How would the mapping be overridden outside of the class of SomeEntity (like how @AttributeOverride works - overriding a mapping in class A from class B)

Comment: Most likely there is no way to do that.